# jquery delay doesn't work

Tags: jquery

I have the next div:

```
<div id="atack">
    <h1>Example</h1>
    <h2>Example</h2>
</div>
```

the css is:

```
 #ataque{
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border: solid thick;
    display: none;
    background: url('../images/check48.png') no-repeat 10px 10px;
    background-color: #000000;
    position: absolute;
    width: 350px;
    height: 100px;
    top: 1cm ;
    right: 1cm;
    padding-top: 10px;
 }
```

and when the run button is pressed i want to show a message during 5 seconds, i try it with jquery but doesn't work...

The other code is:

```
<form method=GET>
 <input id="vm_action_btn" type=submit name=ataque value="Tipping Point" class="btn" />
 <input type=hidden name=num_exec value=5 >
</form>

<script language="JavaScript">

$(function() {      
$("#vm_action_btn").bind('click', function() {
        $('#atack').show().delay(5000).hide();
    });
}); 
</script>
```

I dont have any idea where is the problem! thx!

Comment: What you mean by "but doesn't work..."?

Comment: This is neither here nor there, but the CSS you've included targets an element with an ID of "ataque", which isn't used in any of your other provided code.  Either it's a typo or it should be removed from your question.

Comment: i made a mistake copying it. The css is ok. The problem is the GET method, because it reload the page so the message is only visible during the load time.

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have it.

The problem was that the form send data to the server side and reload the page. Remember that the div "atack" have in the css display: none so it is hidden. When we do show or fadeIn, and want to delay other effect, it is only visible until the page is load (1 second?).

We can solve this issue this way:

```
$(function() { 

 $("#vm_action_btn").click(function() { 
    $.ajax({ 
     type: "POST",
     url: "operations.php",
     data: 'ataque=go',
     success: function() {
       $('#ataque').fadeIn(50).delay(3000).fadeOut(50);
     }
     });
     return false;
  });
});
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 15):

Give `.hide()` a duration, and it will be added to the default `queue` *(which is the one you're delaying)*.

```
  // just add a 0-------------------v
$('#atack').show().delay(5000).hide(0);
```

This is because a `.delay()` only delays the next item in a queue, and the only items that jQuery queues automatically are animations.

Giving even a `0` duration, jQuery will see it as an animation, and will add the `hide` method to the default queue.

To *manually* queue a function, you pass a function to the `queue()` method.

```
$('#atack').show()
           .delay(5000)
           .queue(function() {
               $(this).hide()
                      .dequeue();
           });
```

Comment: It doesn't work... I think the problem is that the method GET reload the page, so the message is only visible during the html load time... Thx!!

Comment: @gekon: Do you *want* the page to reload? If not, change the event type from `click` to `submit`, and add `return false;`.

Comment: Yes, because there is php code that take the data that have been sent and use it...

Answer (score 2):

`delay()` only works for effects (`fadeIn`, `fadeOut`, etc). It doesn't work for `show()` and `hide()`. You could always do a fast `fadeOut(50)` if you wanted.

From the jQuery docs"

> Added to jQuery in version 1.4, the .delay() method allows us to delay
>   the execution of functions that follow it in the queue. It can be used
>   with the standard effects queue or with a custom queue. Only
>   subsequent events in a queue are delayed; for example this will not
>   delay the no-arguments forms of .show() or .hide() which do not use
>   the effects queue.

Comment: The problem is the get method because it reloads the page, so the message is only visible during the load time. If I remove the form it works properly.

Thx!!

Comment: So are you saying it works before the form is submitted, not after? If so, just change `bind` to `on` or `live`.